# bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/var/www"

Tags: debian, sftp, chmod

I created a new group and user so it can connect to server using SFTP. This user's directory is set to `/var/www`. Running `ls -ld` gave me following result:

> drwxr-xr-x 4 root sftponly 4096 Aug 12 04:05 /var/www/

`sftponly` is the group and `mysftpuser` is the user which is part of this group.

I was able to successfully connect using SFTP client but was unable to delete any file inside `www`. So I ran following command to change permission:

> sudo chmod 775 /var/www/

Now running `ls -ld` gives me following result:

> drwxrwxr-x 4 root sftponly 4096 Aug 12 04:05 /var/www/

But now when ever I try to connect to SFTP using user `mysftpuser` I get error in `auth.log`

> fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/var/www"

What did I do wrong and how to fix this issue?

EDIT

**sshd_config**

> Match group sftponly
>   ChrootDirectory /var/www
>   X11Forwarding no
>   AllowTcpForwarding no
>   ForceCommand internal-sftp

Comment: I found out that if I run `sudo chmod 755 /var/www` then I am able to connect to FTP but cannot delete. If I change it back to `sudo chmod 775 /var/www` then I can't connect. I want to be able to connect and delete both.

Comment: Set 755 on /var/www and put the content in a subfolder of /var/www.

Comment: This is what I am already doing. If I set `sudo chmod 755 /var/www` then I cannot create, delete or rename any folder or file inside it. Only read works.

Comment: I have updated my post with `sshd_config` setting in case someone wants to see.

Comment: ChrootDirectory
             Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication.  At session startup sshd(8) checks that all components of the pathname are root-owned direc-
             tories which are not writable by any other user or group.  After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory.

Comment: So what do you suggest to fix this issue?

Comment: Anyone has a suggestion? I have been trying for hours to fix this issue but no luck? ٰ I created a new dir inside `/var/www` but it has the same issue. Even if I give 777 permission on `/var/www` then I cannot connect to SFTP. It will only connect if `/var/www/` has 755 permission but then it won't let me delete, rename etc.